# What "price" is there for mundane magic like teleporting?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In *Once Upon a Time*, we are told ad nauseam that "all magic comes with a price". For instance, Rumplestiltskin becoming the Dark One gives him a physically ugly appearance and Regina's curse required her to sacrifice the only person she cared about.

But what about mundane magic, such as teleporting? This is done fairly often, yet there isn't any obvious price to it. But it must, since the phrase is that "*all* magic comes with a price".

So what price does this sort of magic have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I would be hesitant to take that phrase literally. It is more of a warning against the *abuse* of magic than a description of its mechanics. The mantra is meant to remind those people that magic rarely solves your problem without creating more of it. That would seem to apply mostly to those major spells that appear to allow someone to take the easy way out of a problem, and not so much to the spells that are "utilitarian", like teleporting.

Having said that, the "price" that one has to pay for magic appears to be related to several different aspects of the spell:

- How powerful or significant the effect is
- How dangerous or harmful to others it is
- How much benefit the caster is going to personally get

In this sense, teleportation magic would be an incredibly cheap spell; it's mostly a "utility" spell, in the sense that it's more of a convenience than anything else:

- The effect -- moving from point A to point B -- is something that could be accomplished in a mundane sense, it just would take longer
- In and of itself, teleporation has no harmful effect on other people. (What the caster *does* upon teleporting is a different question.)
- The caster mostly gains some extra free time that would have been wasted by walking.

Since the cost is likely small, it's hard to say exactly what that is. In other, similar magical settings, the cost would be one of "energy" from the caster's own personal reserves; in other words, casting the spell makes them a little tired.

This is in contrast to the bigger spells we've seen, like The Curse itself: that effect was so strong and so wide-spread and so harmful, it required an actual human sacrifice to accomplish.

For many of the magic users, there is also a larger sense of the cost they pay to use magic being the cost of their soul. If we ignore the fairies (who's magic seems to come at the cost of "mining fairy dust") and Emma (who seems to be an anomoly), most of the magic users we've seen have become corrupted by their magic in some sense, or at least paid some serious emotional price. It may be significant that we've only ever seen the "bad guys" use teleportation magic (I don't remember Emma or Elsa doing so), so perhaps those casters are *constantly* paying the price for all of the small spells the use on a regular basis.

Comment: Your last comment about only the "bad guys" using teleportation magic and thus constantly paying the price is really intriguing. Not sure if that's what the show creators had in mind, but it makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: If the promos/previews for this season are anything to go by, we may get to watch Emma go dark-side; it will be interesting to see if she suddenly start's bamfing all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer, but I've thought about this question for a while, so here goes. The way I see it, characters in Once Upon a Time have less in the way of 'free will' than regular people in our world - fate seems to be a constant driving force, more or less inescapable. Villains get foiled despite having every advantage, heroes make sacrifices but "get their happy endings", some entire realms prevent any life progress (Land of Untold Stories, Neverland, etc.). It's a world where fate rules and destinies are inescapable (except by using objects whose specific and only function is to alter fate - the shears of destiny).

I've noticed that those who use magic, and use it constantly, seem to 'pay the price' by being dealt bad hands consistently by fate. Even after redemption and becoming a hero, how much bad fate has Regina had to deal with? How much happiness has Zelena had? Rumplestiltskin repeatedly alienates all around him, especially those he cares about (we can see that as his fate, the 'price' for his magic - not to mention the time when his heart actually exploded to pay for centuries of dark magic).

This doesn't just apply to dark magic users - Merlin's fate was not happy; he never got a happy ending, instead was trapped in a tree by his love, tethered to a sword by the man who was supposed to be his ally and friend, and even killed by his love for a curse. Emma's the Savior, and as we know from Season 6, all Saviors are destined to die protecting everyone else. You can see this as the 'price' from fate - all light magic a savior uses is a loan of sorts, that they inevitably pay back by dying for their friends.

This isn't just limited to magic wielders themselves (though is more obvious with them). In Season 1, the Genie warns King Leopold that he has "granted a thousand and one wishes" and had "seen them end poorly a thousand and one times". The King's wish, as benevolent as it was, gave him a nasty twist of fate and he paid the price for it with his life. The people who ask for help from the Dark One often have to pay the price - though this is sometimes avoided, and they get genuine help that comes without harsh twists of fate to pay. Why is that? Because they pay the price for magic through the cost of their deal with the Dark One. In this way, they've already paid, and the price in fate falls on the Dark One instead (just added to his or her tally). When Regina got magic from the Dark One (Emma) to heal Robin *without* making a deal, a Fury later came to collect the unpaid price from him (even though the magic in question was healing - saving a life).

These are just a few examples, but it's a pretty constant theme I've seen throughout all seasons of the show. Everyone but the people in the Land Without Magic (Storybrook excluded) are governed rigidly by inescapable fate. All magic (good or evil, dark or light, good or bad intentions) comes with a price - even mundane, utilitarian magic just adds to the debt a person has to fate, and the debt is paid with a worse fate.

EDIT: Side note on fairy magic - fairies are light magic users, and neither they nor the people they use magic to help have to pay the price in fate. As you already said, though, their magic is fueled by fairy dust. As a finite and consumable 'fuel', it seems that it takes the place of the price for the magic.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A well-thought out answer! Late answers are always good if the add new perspectives.